# /app/etc/local.xml not working for me?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, cache, local.xml

I have a client's website in magento 1.9.2.0. Am trying to edit database details and admin custom url in `app/etc/local.xml` but no changes reflecting.

when I do research for this, they asking for clean the cache, and check if any extra xml file exist in `app/etc` folder.

So I have deleted cache in `var/cache, var/session folder. var/tmp` folder is also empty. 
and in `app/etc` folder, here is no extra xml file.

Is there any way to know which file is loading as `local.xml` means where from database details coming.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you are in correct root directory .
- Check the website url , `magerun config:get web/` (if you dont have
  magerun go to 'core_config_data' table in db and find the path
  web/secure/base_url , make sure it has a '/' in the end )
- Flush magento cache from admin https://d.pr/free/i/QK3Et0

Comment: thanks, it's working for me. I was skip the basic thing. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped :) .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have backup file of local.xml in same directory(app/etc/), like local-1.xml or local.xml1,etc .

Because sometimes magento consider that files also as its configuration file.

If you need, take the backup file at somewhere, and try it after clearing cache. Also make sure the file and folder permissions. It places the major role.

Comment: I have checked the app/etc forlder, here is no any extra xml file.

Comment: Then take local.xml backup at other location and remove the file. Now try to run your website. It will ask to install magento again, give your database details correctly now. It won't affect anything else.   For safer case : take DB backup aswell.